# How can I edit comment meta value before it is saved?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, save-post, comment-meta

I have introduced a custom field in comments form using add_comment_meta() function.

I would like to know if there is a way to edit the data of the comment meta just before the post data is saved so that every time the data is replaced with my value before it is saved.

Lets say that the key is `brand_id`.

I have used the following function to edit the `custom_meta` Value

```
function update_comments_meta($post_id) {
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    if (!empty($comments)) {
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            echo $comment;
            update_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'brand_id', 'hard_coder');
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'update_comments_meta');
```

Comment: You want to update all `brand_id` comment meta values, related to a given post, each time that post is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)" action-hook

Add the code below into functions.php and enchance with your comment_meta code.

```
function update_comments_meta( $post_id ) {
   // Do whatever add/update_comment_meta code you need
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_comments_meta' );
```

---

**UPDATE.**

As an example i've attach code below. It performs on post save/update action fired. Code gets current post comments (all) then looping through received comment object it launch `update_comment_meta` with ID extracted from comments object.

```
function update_comments_meta($post_id) {
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    if (!empty($comments))
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            update_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'YOUR_META_KEY', 'YOUR_META_VALUE');
        }
}

add_action('save_post', 'update_comments_meta');
```

Hope this is the case that you where interested in. Code tested on 4.3 twentyfifteen.

Refferences:

1. [update_comment_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_comment_meta)
2. [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Comment: how can i use it to modify a post variable that is a custom field `brand_id`

Comment: I have updated accordingto your code ....please check it dosent work

Comment: I've updated answer with an example of code. Your `update_comment_meta` receive wrong input data (You pass post_ID instead comment_ID). **Additionally**: In your question you specify that you're searching for a way how to update "comment meta just before the post data is saved". If you want to update specific comment, just add `update_comment_meta('SPECIFIC_COMMENT_ID', 'YOUR_META_KEY', 'YOUR_META_VALUE');` to the code posted in original answer.

Comment: thanks for your update ....but i am sorry to say that it is not working yet.   Second this is that i tried to check it manually and went to this website https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments to find that there is no field as comment_ID

Comment: How about using https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment for comment meta?

Comment: BTW I have used ACF_Field to add field to comment form

Comment: The code example provided is tested and it works. Answering your question about `get_comments()`: it receives `post_ID` as a parameter and return `$comments` object that contains all comments for `post_ID` given. 

Considering your answer about ACF plugin, please provide more info:
1) Check is code in answer works. (Create few comments and "update" comments-post, then goto database  table `$prefix_commentmeta` and find a value-key pair stored by `update_comment_meta` there.)
2) Provide more code related to the form implementation, plugin version, plugin addons used for that, etc.